# HTTP Response Always Cause I/Oexception using Android 

Tags: android

> below code is giving I/O excpetion always while i checked the URI in browser its working and I Internet permission is in Android Manifest file is given . I am invoking like this from on click button

```
     CheckMetaData cmd = new CheckMetaData();
        cmd.execute(url);
  ---------class def ---  
private class CheckMetaData extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,InputStream> {    
     protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params) {


                    String url=params[0];

                    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

                            try {

                               HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
                               final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                               if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                                  Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                                      "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url);
                                  return null;
                               }

                               HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
                                   return getResponseEntity.getContent();

                            }
                            catch (IOException e) {
                               getRequest.abort();
                               Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);

                            }        
                            return null; 
            }
```

Comment: In the `catch` block use `e.printStackTrace()` and check logcat to see  more detailed information about what is failing.

Comment: 08-03 16:46:22.293: E/AndroidRuntime(787): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
but how come ?? I am using Asynctask and this activity is getting launch from previous activity like protected void onPostExecute(char[] result){ ... JSONObject vehicle = new JSONObject(new String(result));
    Intent available=new Intent();
       available.setClass(DattabActivity.this, Available_Surveys.class);
       available.putExtra("userid", vehicle.getString("SurveyorId"));
       startActivity(available);

Comment: My only guess is you are returning the `InputStream` with this line...`return getResponseEntity.getContent();`. That means the `InputStream` is returned as a result to the `onPostExecute(...)` method which is run on the main/UI thread. Do the processing of the `InputStream` in the `doInBackground(...)` method and that might solve the problem.